# How can I clear a setInterval on a single element when it's been applied to multiple?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple items with a `setInterval` applied that animates the contents. I have a `clearInterval` set that stops the animation on hover. Of course this stops all animating items. I want to clear the interval on only the hovered over item and allow the others to to continue to animate. I'm fine with the animations getting out of sync with each other.

```
var boxInterval = setInterval(startBox, 3000);

$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    clearInterval(boxInterval);
});

$('.box').mouseleave(function(){
    boxInterval = setInterval(startBox, 3000);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2rfoq7a/) : notice hovering over one pauses the other. hovering off start them both (after 3 seconds)

Comment: can you show the code for startBox or a working fiddle??

Comment: `setInterval` is applied to the whole window, you may want to add some flags (boolean) to perform or not actions on certain elements

Comment: @RajaSekar, added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference returned by `setTimeout` / `setInterval` is not attached to an element. You'll have to save each reference uniquely. I'd go with a [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) property...

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    clearInterval($(this).data('timer'));
});

$('.box').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).data('timer', setInterval(startBox, 3000));
});
```

Comment: I tried getting a unique reference for each by placing the `setInterval` into an `.each()` but that freaked things out so I assumed I was on the wrong track.

Comment: It took some refactoring but I found the issue I was having. I was running another `each` that caused an odd delay. Fixed the issue with your answer as inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the two events are always triggered in pair, so save `boxInterval` for each items.